# How can I create a custom list in C++ for Qml?

Tags: c++, qt, custom-controls, qml, qtquick2

I want to create a custom list for using in Qml (I want a paginated flow list like MacOS's Launchpad). I want to implement it using C++ because of performance.
Can anyone advise me how to start to implement a custom list in C++ for using in Qml?

Thank you

Comment: Are you having a specific problem? This is all documented pretty thoroughly here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html

Comment: Most of the overhead is from drawing the list, which will still be QML. You may gain from memory usage with C++ lists, if your lists are massive, otherwise I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Yes, I have a specific problem... I want to create a horizontal list of flowing list (a list of list!). Just like Launchpad of Mac OS. This requires computation for resize/drag/add/remove in list and in list items. On this events, may cause to reorder items. Also list has many items.

Answer (score 0):

There is good enough official documentation about using models in QML. First of all you need to know what is Model-View approach -- [Models and Views in Qt Quick](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html). Later on you can see exactly what you want here: [Using C++ Models with Qt Quick Views](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html). My recommendation for you (as for beginner) is to look more precisely at **QObjectList-based model**.

Also I prepared little working exaple which can be used as starting point for you -- https://github.com/troyane/StackOverflow-pro/tree/master/custom-list-for-qml

Comment: Thank you, but I already know about Model and View and also C++ Models. I want to create a new custom list. Each item is another list (flow list). In other words, I want a paginated flow list. Each page is a flow list. How can I implement this complex list using C++?

Comment: 1. Write all your details in your question above. 2. Take a look at links -- there are comprehensive documentation. 3. Take a look at  code I provide you. Try it, think on how you can use (improve) it for your specific task. And then, when you'll get specific question -- write it here with additional information about what have you already done, and what do you still need to be done. 4. Never wait for already ready solution.